# Kronecker Product in Armadillo

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, armadillo

Is there a direct implementation of the Kronecker product of two sparse matrices using the armadillo library?

The usual function:

```
   kron()
```

Does not seem to work, and I can't seem to find any reference to an implementation.

My thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a mcve(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Maybe there isn't one? Armadillo started as a _dense_ matrix library, and while support for _sparse_ matrices is growing, there may still be holes.